# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, update

Quiero hacer una actualización en una base de datos la cual extraigo unos datos por método post desde un formulario. Esos datos los ingreso en la consulta mysql y me da el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or 
access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right 
syntax to use near '`NOMPROD`='ODIN', `TELA1`='polar', 
`TELA2`='polar', `TELA3`='polar', `PESO1`=...' at line 1 in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_Mr.GuauGuau\function\funciones.php:137 Stack 
trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_Mr.GuauGuau\function\funciones.php(137): 
PDOStatement->execute() #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_Mr.GuauGuau\modulos\costoPro.php(4): 
include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_Mr.GuauGuau\admin.php(35): 
include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_Mr.GuauGuau\function\funciones.php on line 137
```

el form es este:

```
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <!-- telas 1-->
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for=""class="form-label">Tela 1</label>
                        <select name="mod-tela1" id="" class="form-control">
                          <?php foreach($listaTela as $listatelas){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $listatelas['TELAS'];?>"><?php echo $listatelas['TELAS'];?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for=""class="form-label">Precio de tela</label>
                        <select name="mod-pre-tela1" id="" class="form-control">
                          <?php foreach($listaTela as $listatelas){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $listatelas['PRECIOTELA'];?>"><?php echo $listatelas['TELAS'];?> <?php echo " $ ".$listatelas['PRECIOTELA'];?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for=""class="form-label">Peso</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod-peso1" value="<?php echo $rec_peso1_cost ?>">
                        
                      </div> 
                    </div>

                    <!-- telas 2-->
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for=""class="form-label">Tela 1</label>
                        <select name="mod-tela2" id="" class="form-control">
                          <?php foreach($listaTela as $listatelas){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $listatelas['TELAS'];?>"><?php echo $listatelas['TELAS'];?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for=""class="form-label">Precio de tela</label>
                        <select name="mod-pre-tela2" id="" class="form-control">
                          <?php foreach($listaTela as $listatelas){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $listatelas['PRECIOTELA'];?>"><?php echo $listatelas['TELAS'];?> <?php echo " $ ".$listatelas['PRECIOTELA'];?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for=""class="form-label">Peso</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod-peso2" value="<?php echo $rec_peso2_cost ?> ">
                      </div> 
                    </div>

                    <!-- telas 3-->

                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for=""class="form-label">Tela 1</label>
                        <select name="mod-tela3" id="" class="form-control">
                          <?php foreach($listaTela as $listatelas){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $listatelas['TELAS'];?>"><?php echo $listatelas['TELAS'];?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for=""class="form-label">Precio de tela</label>
                        <select name="mod-pre-tela3" id="" class="form-control">
                          <?php foreach($listaTela as $listatelas){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $listatelas['PRECIOTELA'];?>"><?php echo $listatelas['TELAS'];?> <?php echo " $ ".$listatelas['PRECIOTELA'];?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for=""class="form-label">Peso</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod-peso3" value="<?php echo $rec_peso3_cost ?> ">
                      </div> 
                    </div>

                    <!--otros-->

                    <div class="form-row"> 
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="">Costurera</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="mod-costurera">
                          <?php foreach ($listaTela as $telas ){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $telas['COSTURERA'];?>">  <?php echo  $telas['COSTURERA'];?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="">Etiquetas</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod-etiquetas"  value=" <?php echo  $telas['ETIQUETAS'];?>">
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="">Otros</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod-otros"  value=" <?php echo $telas['OTROS'];?>">
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="">IVA %</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod-iva"  value="<?php echo $telas['IVA'];?>">
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="">Nombre del producto</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod-nombre" placeholder="nombre del producto">
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="">Talle</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod-talles" placeholder="Talles">
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="">Articulo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod-art" placeholder="num de Art">
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="heddin" value="<?php echo $rec_id_cost;?>" name="id_producto">
                  
              </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="btn-actualizar">Actualizar</button>
                </div>
                </form>
```

y la consulta mysql es esta:

```
 $sentencia=$query->prepare("UPDATE `costosproductos` 
   SET `IDPROD`,`NOMPROD`=:NOMBRE, `TELA1`=:TELA1, 
    `TELA2`=:TELA2,`TELA3`=:TELA3, `PESO1`=:PESO1,
    `PESO2`=:PESO2, `PESO3`=:PESO3, `COSTURERAPRO`=:COSTURERAPRO,
    `ETIQUETASPRO`=:ETIQUETASPRO, `OTROSPRO`=:OTROSPRO, `IVAPRO`=:IVAPRO,
    `ARTICULO`=:ARTICULO, `GANANCIA`=:GANANCIA, `SUBTOTAL`=:SUBTOTAL,
    `TOTAL`=:TOTAL, `TALLESPROD`=:TALLESPROD WHERE IDPROD=$id_producto");

      $sentencia->bindParam(":NOMBRE", $mod_nombre);
      $sentencia->bindParam(":TELA1", $mod_Tela);
      $sentencia->bindParam(":TELA2", $mod_Tela2);
      $sentencia->bindParam(":TELA3", $mod_Tela3);
      $sentencia->bindParam(":PESO1", $mod_peso);
      $sentencia->bindParam(":PESO2", $mod_peso2);
      $sentencia->bindParam(":PESO3", $mod_peso3);
      $sentencia->bindParam(":COSTURERAPRO", $mod_Costurera);
      $sentencia->bindParam(":ETIQUETASPRO", $mod_Etiquetas);
      $sentencia->bindParam(":OTROSPRO", $mod_Otros);
      $sentencia->bindParam(':IVAPRO', $calculoIva_mod);
      $sentencia->bindParam(':ARTICULO',$mod_articulo);
      $sentencia->bindParam(':GANANCIA',$ganancia_mod);
      $sentencia->bindParam(':SUBTOTAL', $subtotal_mod);
      $sentencia->bindParam(':TOTAL', $total_mod);
      $sentencia->bindParam(':TALLESPROD', $mod_talles);
      $sentencia->execute();

      echo  "<script>alert('registro actualizado');</script>";        

   }
```

desde ya muchas gracias y espero haber postaedo de forma correcta

Comment: Mandas un set de IDPROD, pero no lo añades ningún valor. Creo que SQL se queda esperando el valor y te da error al no recibirlo.

Comment: Si `IDPROD` es clave primaria, nunca se actualiza una clave primaria.

Comment: Aparte de lo ya comentado por los compañeros, esto rompe el concepto de consulta preparada, haciendo el código vulnerable: `WHERE IDPROD=$id_producto`  Por tanto, deberías poner un marcador también ahí y pasar `$id_producto` usando `bindParam` como haces con los otros valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo creo que debes de quitar en el codigo SQL el campo IDPROD ya que no le estas pasando ningun parametro.

Ademas esta diciendo que hay un error de sintaxis, eso es porlas comillas, me parece que debes de revisar
"UPDATE NOMBRE_TABLA SET CAMPO1=:VALOR1, CAMPO2=:VALOR2 WHERE ID=$ID_DESEADO"

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda... fueron muy amables y tome en consideración cada una de las sugerencias. Efectivamente era el campo IDPROD.